# No header files included in file but can still use classes/functions from unincluded header files

Tags: c++, include, translation-unit

Here's some the code from the file in question, called Global.h, which is used in other header files and seems to compile just fine:

```
#pragma once

enum SType {null, lab, assignment, testPrep};
enum Code {none, 123, 222, 333, 432};

template<typename D>
bool validate(D task = string, D date = string) {

    bool result = true;

    if (task.size() < 3) {
        cout << "Task too simple, please elaborate." << endl;
        result = false;
    }
    else if (task.size() > 50) {
        cout << "Task too detailed. Only 30 chars allowed." << endl;
        task.empty();
        result = false;
    }

if (date == "02/20/93") {
    date.empty();
    date = "My birthday!";
}

    return result;

}
```

As you can see I'm able to use string and ostream objects without declaring the use of a namespace or particular file. Obviously this means that Global.h is drawing the information from somewhere else, but I'm curious as to where this information is coming from? I always thought that a header file will only reconize code from other files if they've been included with the #include directive in the file itself, so I'm not sure how this is happening and am curious to know what's going on.

Comment: you mean that you compile it using `g++ -c Global.h` and it works?

Comment: @Jean-Francois Fabre   It works in visual studio, not sure what the gcc compiler would do about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It's just that whatever is including this `Global.h` header file must be already `#include`ing all the required headers.

Somewhat of a simplication: an `#include` statement gets replaced by logically inserting the contents of the `#include`d file in place of the `#include` statement itself. When you compile a translation unit, all `#include` statements are processed in this manner. As if all `#include` statements get logically replaced by the contents of the referenced file. The final result is a single logical source file, a translation unit, that gets compiled from start to finish.

So, if after all `#include` statement are processed in this manner, as long as the requisite header files, `<iostream>`, and others, get logically inserted in the logical translation unit prior to the classes and other resources from `<iostream>` that are referenced from this header file, this translation unit will compile without issues. Whether it's the same header file that `#include`s the required header files, `<iostream>` and others; or some other header file that gets `#include`d earlier, which `#include`s these header files; it doesn't matter.

It is true that good practice indicates that each file should explicitly `#include` its prerequisites. But if it doesn't, as long as some other header file has already been `#include`d, the translation unit will still compile.